# How to iterate through independent variables, performing multiple linear regressions using the tidyverse framework?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, genetics, broom

My data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

myData <- structure(list(Subjects = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
8L, 7L), Gene1 = c(0.318630087617032, -0.58179068471591, 0.714532710891568, 
-0.825259425862769, -0.359862131395465, 0.0898861437775305, 0.0962744602851301, 
-0.201633952183354, 0.739840499878431, 0.123379501088869), Variant1 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L), Variant2 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L), Variant3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Variant4 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), Age = c(81L, 60L, 85L, 87L, 76L, 78L, 88L, 64L, 
90L, 75L), Sex = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), RIN = c(6L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L), ABG = structure(c(4L, 5L, 
8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("F1", "F10", "F2", 
"F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Subjects", "Gene1", 
"Variant1", "Variant2", "Variant3", "Variant4", "Age", "Sex", 
"RIN", "ABG"))

myData
   Subjects       Gene1 Variant1 Variant2 Variant3 Variant4 Age Sex RIN ABG
1         4  0.31863009        1        0        1        1  81   0   6  F3
2         3 -0.58179068        0        0        1        2  60   1   6  F4
3         5  0.71453271        1        2        0        1  85   0   8  F8
4         1 -0.82525943        2        2        2        0  87   1   6  F2
5         9 -0.35986213        2        0        0        0  76   0   8  F5
6         6  0.08988614        1        2        1        1  78   1   7 F10
7        10  0.09627446        0        2        1        0  88   0   8  F2
8         2 -0.20163395        1        2        1        2  64   0   7  F3
9         8  0.73984050        2        2        2        1  90   1   7  F6
10        7  0.12337950        0        0        1        1  75   1   6  F1
```

`Gene1` is my dependent variable and `Variant1`, `Variant2`, `Variant3` and `Variant4` are my independent variables. `Age`, `Sex`, `RIN` and `ABG` are my covariates. Using the tidyverse framework (broom/dplyr/purrr/map) I'd like to iterate through `Variant1:Variant4` performing the following linear regressions using a linear mixed model:

`lmer(Gene1~Variant1+Age+Sex+RIN+(1|ABG), myData)` for **Variant1**,
`lmer(Gene1~Variant2+Age+Sex+RIN+(1|ABG), myData)` for **Variant2**, so on ...

At the end, I'd like generate a results table with beta coefficients (Estimate), Std.Err and pValues for all Variant* (possibly using tidy/augment/glance??).

PS. The number of Variant* my vary.

Thank you!

Comment: Pls no screenshots. Please create a reprex with input and expected output and post samples of your data using `dput()`

Comment: See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, you are more likely to get a prompt answer if you don't make people type out data, and if you condense the problem to show what you have tried and what particular sticking point/area of misunderstanding you have so we can give a targeted answer.

Comment: @dylanjm and Calum You: sorry for the screenshots, been a while since I lasted posted a question on the forum. Updated the post to include a reprex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your problem you can `gather()` in order to utilize `group_split()` on all the different kinds of variants. From that point we can iterate over each split data.frame and run the linear model. Inside of the `map()` we'll `broom::tidy()` the data and add a column to distinguish the estimates for each model. I used `map_df()` to end up with a single dataframe but you can also just use `map()` to end up with a list of data.frames.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(broom)

dat <- tribble(~Subjects, ~Gene1, ~Variant1, ~Variant2, ~Variant3, ~Variant4, ~Age, ~Sex, ~RIN, ~ABG,
        1,     -0.82525943,  2,      2,       2,       0,     87,   1,   6,     "F2",
        2,     -0.20163395,  1,      2,       1,       2, 64  , 0 ,  7,       "F3",
        3,     -0.58179068,  0,      0,       1,       2, 60  , 1 ,  6,       "F4",
        4,      0.31863009,  1,      0,       1,       1, 81  , 0 ,  6,       "F3",
        5,      0.71453271,  1,      2,       0,       1, 85  , 0 ,  8,       "F8",
        6,      0.08988614,  1,      2,       1,       1, 78  , 1 ,  7,      "F10",
        7,      0.12337950,  0,      0,       1,       1, 75  , 1 ,  6,       "F1",
        8,      0.73984050,  2,      2,       2,       1, 90  , 1 ,  7,       "F6",
        9,     -0.35986213,  2,      0,       0,       0, 76  , 0 ,  8,       "F5",
        10,     0.09627446,  0,      2,       1,       0,  88,   0,   8,       "F2")

dat %>% 
  gather(key = "variants", value = "var_value", Variant1:Variant4) %>% 
  group_split(variants) %>% 
  map_df(~lmer(Gene1~var_value+Age+Sex+RIN+(1|ABG), data = .x) %>% 
        tidy() %>% 
        mutate(variant_group = unique(.x$variants)))
#> # A tibble: 28 x 6
#>    term                  estimate std.error statistic group   variant_group
#>    <chr>                    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        
#>  1 (Intercept)           -3.91      1.96     -2.00    fixed   Variant1     
#>  2 var_value             -0.280     0.120    -2.34    fixed   Variant1     
#>  3 Age                    0.0401    0.00905   4.43    fixed   Variant1     
#>  4 Sex                    0.00107   0.391     0.00274 fixed   Variant1     
#>  5 RIN                    0.161     0.154     1.05    fixed   Variant1     
#>  6 sd_(Intercept).ABG     0.462    NA        NA       ABG     Variant1     
#>  7 sd_Observation.Resid…  0.00234  NA        NA       Residu… Variant1     
#>  8 (Intercept)           -3.60      2.74     -1.31    fixed   Variant2     
#>  9 var_value             -0.0625    0.202    -0.309   fixed   Variant2     
#> 10 Age                    0.0295    0.0175    1.69    fixed   Variant2     
#> # … with 18 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @dylanjm. Works perfectly. I realized that extracting pValues from linear mixed models is complex [issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/how-to-obtain-the-p-value-check-significance-of-an-effect-in-a-lme4-mixed-mode), but if I wish to calculate one using the Kenward-Roger method in lmerTest::anova(ddf="Kenward-Roger") function, how do I incorporate this into your code so as to merge results generated above with those obtained from lmerTest::anova() for each variant?

Comment: Not quite sure the exact output you're looking for but maybe try piping into `lmerTest::ranova()` before `tidy()`. You might have to filter out the <none> rows though. Other than that, I'm unsure. Please ensure to mark my answer as correct if it satisfies your original question.